# Referencing pre-built shared libraries from JNI library on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to build a JNI interface to an existing C++ code base.  I have successfully built a .so file for my JNI function, and can successfully call that function from within Java code.

When I move to the next step, which is to call a function in libpng (compiled to a .so file with the NDK tool chain), I am able to successfully build the shared library associated with my JNI function, and the .MK file causes libpng12.so to be copied into the libs/armeabi directory as it should.

Deploying the application to the emulator places both the JNI .so and the libpng.so into the lib directory of the application folder under /data.  Calling System.loadLibrary for my JNI library causes that code to be found in my application's lib directory.

However, I then get an UnsatisfiedLinkError when the code tries to access the libpng.so file.  Using strace on the emulator, I see that it is trying to load the libpng.so from /system/lib, rather than from the same location that the JNI library was loaded from.

Is there some way to control where referenced libraries are loaded from?  It doesn't seem that they should have to be installed in /system/lib; the fact that deploying the application places the referenced .so file in the app's lib dirctory seems to indicate that it would be found there.

For what it's worth, here's the .MK file we are using:
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := png12
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libpng12.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /home/jipping/libpng-1.2.44

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := PNGLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := PNGLib.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := png12

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/cygdrive /c/Users/mcfall/workspace/AndroidCalculator/jni -lpng12
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /home/mcfall/libpng-1.2.44

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the `libpng12.so` using `System.loadLibrary` as well. Do this before loading your jni library so all needed symbols are already loaded.